# Change CSS style of a class with javascript, but not in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Let's assume we have lots of elements (see [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hyL2fu9m/)):

```
<div class="yes">Hello1</div>
<div class="yes">Hello2</div>
<div class="yes">Hello3</div>
<div class="yes">Hello4</div>
<div class="yes">Hello5</div>
```

with the same class called `yes` which has a simple CSS style :

```
.yes { color:red; }
```

Now I would like to change the style of the `yes` class.

*Of course*, we can change CSS style of this class with Javascript by using

```
var yesarray = document.querySelectorAll('.yes');

for (var i = 0, len = yesarray.length; i < len; i++) {
    yesarray[i].style.color = 'black';
}
```

(or even more easily with jQuery, with `$('.yes').css(...)` ...)

But then all these changes will be **stored in the DOM** :

[image]

*This is not very elegant if I have lots of elements, that all these styles are "rendered 
in the DOM" like this.*

**Question:**

**How to change CSS style with Javascript such that the style change is not stored in the DOM, but modified in the loaded-in-memory CSS instead?**

Comment: You're doing it the right way, it doesn't matter if the styles are inline.

Comment: @adeneo it does matter for me, because 1/ I can have thousands of such elements,   2/ Later I want to serialize the DOM structure. I find that having a thousand of inline styles is inelegant / increases the serialized data.

Comment: If you have thousands of elements and you're going to serialize the DOM structure, you're probably doing something else wrong, as that seems unnecessary. You can of course append a style tag to the head instead, but that's really even worse practice, even if it soves the issue of having styles on each element.

Comment: Can you create all your classes before-hand and simply use javascript to change the class instead of CSS properties?(to avoid inline styles)

Comment: that's what I was doing in the meantime, and I think it may solve the problem @Schmalzy :) . If you want to post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: MrPk beat me to it.. Its probably better to append classes as he said anyways.

Comment: @adeneo I don't like creating/updating `<style>` elements either, but in the rare case of needing a *lot* of different effective style values, the combinatorics of a static solution can be problematic. (Like, if you needed to compute a color value and apply it to selected elements across a large DOM.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't edit the CSS style page, but you can do something else.

You are doing in the right way but with a wrong approach.

You have to add ANTOHER style to each element with "yes" class.
This style can be called in your example "approved"

So your jquery call will be:

EDIT: Schmalzy said correctly: `$('.yes').addClass('approved');`

equivalent of:

```
 $('.yes').each(){
  $(this).addClass('approved');
}
```

and previusly you declared in your stylesheet:

```
.approved {
 color: black
}
```

So in your page you will store classes (elegant and shorter) and not inline style.

Comment: No need for the `.each()` `$('.yes').addClass('approved');` would do the same thing.

Comment: No need to add a class to all the elements. Add a single class to the `<body>` tag and use a CSS descendant selector to enforce the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying every DOM node with class "yes", you can use the power of CSS descendant selectors to make the change a lot cheaper:

CSS:

```
.yes {
  color: blue; /* or whatever */
}

.approved .yes {
  color: black;
}
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$("body").toggleClass("approved", shouldApprove());
```

Only one DOM node is updated (though, of course, the browser still has to recompute the layout of the whole page).